# Как поместить фигуру за фигурой

Tags: javascript, html, canvas

Могли бы вы напомнить мне, каким образом можно поставить одну фигуру за вторую фигуру при помощи canvas? Например сделать так, чтобы круг находился за квадратом(квадрат был поверх круга). Искал в интернете, ничего полезного не нашел.

Спаcибо за помощь.

Comment: Михаил, т.к. вы указываете необходимые метки для вопроса, то помещать эти же данные в заголовок вопороса не требуется.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

В canvas работает z-index по типу "то что нарисовано выше то расположено ниже"

Если сомнваетесь то переместите `ctx.fillStyle = 'red'; ctx.fillRect(25, 25, 100, 100);` выше кода circle

```js
let canvas = document.getElementById('canvas');
let ctx = canvas.getContext('2d');



const centerX = canvas.width / 2;
const centerY = canvas.height / 2;
const radius = 70;
ctx.beginPath();
ctx.arc(centerX, centerY, radius, 0, 2 * Math.PI, false);
ctx.fillStyle = 'green';
ctx.fill();
ctx.closePath();


ctx.fillStyle = 'red';
ctx.fillRect(25, 25, 100, 100);
```

```html
<canvas id="canvas"></canvas>
```

Такой же вариант но квадрат за кругом

```js
let canvas = document.getElementById('canvas');
let ctx = canvas.getContext('2d');

ctx.fillStyle = 'red';
ctx.fillRect(25, 25, 100, 100);

const centerX = canvas.width / 2;
const centerY = canvas.height / 2;
const radius = 70;
ctx.beginPath();
ctx.arc(centerX, centerY, radius, 0, 2 * Math.PI, false);
ctx.fillStyle = 'green';
ctx.fill();
ctx.closePath();
```

```html
<canvas id="canvas"></canvas>
```

Comment: Спасибо, понял, разобрался.